# Is the default delimiter of xargs is newline rather than blanks?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

I try this command:

```
echo  tony mary | xargs -i -n1 echo "{} said: hello"
```

I think that xargs's default delimiter is blank characters including whitespace, tabs and newlines. So I think the output of echo should be split into `tony` and `mary`. And because I add the option `-n1`, I expected it to output

```
tony said: hello
mary said: hello
```

Instead, it outputs:

```
tony mary said: hello
```

Why?

Comment: Have you read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html)? It says *unquoted blanks do not terminate arguments; instead, the input is split at newlines only* when `-i` is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need newline delimited input:

```
$ printf '%s\n' tony mary | xargs -i -n1 echo "{} said: hello"
tony said: hello
mary said: hello
```

This option is now deprecated, instead prefer the use of:

```
xargs -I{} ...
```

Comment: This seems to be a perfectly reasonable answer to a perfectly reasonable question to me.